# Is there a way to Ignore all null values from source during mapping using Mapster when members are IEnumerable<T>

Tags: null, mapping, ienumerable, ef-core-3.1, mapster

I'm using Mapster 5.3.1 with DI in EF Core 3.1 ... and I have a question.. is there a way to ignore all null values in source member during mapping when both members are IEnumerable and both have identical structure.

var tSource = (IEnumerable)
var tDestination = (IEnumerable)

_mapper.Map(tSource, tDestination)

If tSource have a null value I don't want to that value in tDestination.

I hope you guys can help me.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore null property using `IgnoreNullVaules`. https://github.com/MapsterMapper/Mapster/wiki/Shallow-merge#copy-vs-merge

Comment: Thanks your time..I had already read that but i'm still getting null values at destination

Comment: I put this at 
Startup: TypeAdapterConfig.GlobalSettings.Default.PreserveReference(true); 
Configure: TypeAdapterConfig<Tsource, Tdestination> .NewConfig() .IgnoreNullValues(true); Controller: _mapper.Map(dtoGetLinea, _entity) 

Where  tSource = IEnumerable<Tsource> and tDestination = IEnumerable<Tdestination>

Did I miss something?